# How to restart the main method?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a math value.");
        Scanner sayiyaz = new Scanner(System.in);

        if(sayiyaz.hasNextInt()) {
            int sayi1 = sayiyaz.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("I wish u could know what is a math value .");
        }
    }
}
```

In the else block of code i want to restart the "main" method from the beginning and ask the same question.

But how to do that ?

Comment: read a tutorial about loops: [Java Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html)

Comment: You do it by re-running the program :)

Comment: call `main(args)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "X" can be a math value.

Comment: There are numerous ways. You could even use the good-old `goto` directive (no, seriously you can't). The easiest way to ask the same question again would be to put it in some `do-while` or `while` loop.

Comment: @E_net4 other mathematical values include Determinism, Generalisation, Universality, Abstractness - http://scholarworks.umt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1085&context=tme

Comment: @PeteKirkham The joy!

Comment: @E_net4 be simple master.. dont be so addicted of eclecticism.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you serious? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can call it if you want to (like Sudhakar sugested) but i assume that you just want to request the input until you get something that fits your needs in that case you have a better solution

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean done = false;
    Integer sayi1 = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a math value.");
        Scanner sayiyaz = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (sayiyaz.hasNextInt()) {
            sayi1 = sayiyaz.nextInt();
            done = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Input is wrong ");
        }
    } while (!done);

    System.out.println("Here is youre  input " + sayi1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't want to restart main.  This is the entry point used by the Java Virtual machine to start your application.  The simplest way to do what you want is to use a loop, so something like:

```
while (true) {
  System.out.println("Please enter a math value");

  // The rest of your code.

  if (finished)
    break;
}
```

Comment: Aha thats it big master ! Thanks a lot :)  i missed your point of view :)